# How to add event sources

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, calendar, fullcalendar

In my fullcalendar page, I have a (default) event sources area that looks like such:

```
eventSources: [{
    url: '/events/index/',
    color: 'yellow',
    textColor: 'black',
    ignoreTimezone: false
}],
```

I have a model (and view) folder titled `"rentalcars"`. How would I make the events automatically be pulled from that model? This model has start and end dates.

I tried:

```
eventSources: [{
    url: '/rentalcars/index/',
    color: 'yellow',
    textColor: 'black',
    ignoreTimezone: false
}],
```

which certainly does not work. I looked at arshaw's source, and I can tell how to make static events, but I am looking for dynamic ones: ones that will iterate through existing models.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url parameter needs to return whatever the FullCalendar understands and can parse, so judging by the [documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/) you will have to make sure that your `rentelcars` index action returns this particular format:

```
{
        title  : 'event1',
        start  : '2010-01-01'
    },
    {
        title  : 'event2',
        start  : '2010-01-05',
        end    : '2010-01-07'
    },
    {
        title  : 'event3',
        start  : '2010-01-09 12:30:00',
        allDay : false // will make the time show
    }
}
```

So in your `rentalcars_controller.rb` in the `index` definition you will have to make sure that you return this format which looks a lot like JSON to me. So, easiest way would be to have this as your JavaScript:

```
eventSources: [{
  url: '/rentalcars.json',
  color: 'yellow',
  textColor: 'black',
  ignoreTimezone: false
}],
```

And then in your controller you will have something like this:

```
def index
    rentalcar_dates = RentelcarDates.all # assuming this is an object that holds start, end date and maybe the car name

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render :json => rentalcar_dates }
    end
end
```

Comment: Currently rentalcars have many properties, and a start and end date are just two of them. Do I have to make another table which is just called RentalCarDates, with the column names matching exactly to "title,start,end.."? Or can i just take the two columns somehow?

Comment: Yes, you can simply take any columns like so `Rentelcar.all.map { |r| {:title => r.title, :start => r.start, :end => r.end} }`